# Are Make Your Own Gear questions relevant to TGO SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

MYOG (e.g., homemade alcohol stoves or tarp-tents) is a fairly specific activity that is related to the outdoors. Questions about MYOG probably fall in the DIY tag.

There already exist specialized forums for backpackers' MYOG questions. But those forums do not follow the Q&A peer-reviewed model.

Should TGO accept this type of question?

Here is an example question:

> Where can one obtain eVENT material for a MYOG project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, yes, I think (most) make-your-own-gear questions are on-topic; we even have a few already. However, that particular question category ("Where can I buy X") is a shopping question and is off-topic on those grounds.

Comment: Ok. Is "Where can I buy X" also off-topic considering that the challenge for a MYOG is on the availability of the material to a non-manufacturer? i.e. Similar is 'How do I obtain Cuben fiber?' It doesn't really have to do with shopping but on how you can obtain the materials required for projects. Thanks!

Comment: As with most things, it depends on what you're looking for and how you phrase the question. If you ask "Where can I buy _" and the answer is easily found via Amazon or a google search (or similar), then you probably shouldn't ask. If you ask "how can I make or obtain _" some rare material or product not easily found, that is more likely to be accepted.

Comment: Ya, searching for event (eVENT) on google is not much fun. :-)