# Are questions on repairing typical outdoors clothes and footwear ontopic?

Tags: support, scope

Suppose I want to ask a question about how I can seal the hole on my shoes outsole (that appeared after I stepped onto a nail) with enough details on the shoe material of course. That looks like something outdoors enthusiasts should have good knowledge of to me.

Would that be on-topic?

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely. Make your own gear questions and do-it-yourself questions already have their own tags on TGO. This includes tent repairs, shoe repairs, etc.

See Also: [Are Make Your Own Gear questions relevant to TGO SE?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/are-make-your-own-gear-questions-relevant-to-tgo-se)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt. If you are somewhere in Town or a locality, even then you may loose your shoe-sole, or you may break the belt of your floaters, etc.
But yeah, it you try and be specific with the fact that you are somewhere outdoors (far away from where you can find a cobbler or a Shoe Shop), in that case a question which would ask ppl in a manner of *what can be done?* should sound like an Outdoor Activity related Question.

Like: *What I can do if the sole of the shoe is almost seperated?*