# Are questions related to building a 'Make-shift adventure gear' valid on this site?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I wonder, are questions related to building a 'Make-shift adventure gear' valid on this site?
Suppose if I want to make a make-shift gear, say a Tent to start with, are we taking these questions as valid ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they are on topic if they are related to any outdoors activity.

Also, the answers to those questions might useful in case of an emergency situation.

I understand your discomfort.  Personally, I prefer to not reinvent the wheel if the product is well designed, affordable  and available.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and there's even a tag [myog](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myog) for it.

Also see:  [Are Make Your Own Gear questions relevant to TGO SE?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/are-make-your-own-gear-questions-relevant-to-tgo-se)